# If HTTPS is unavailable switch to HTTP

Tags: ios, http, ssl, https, nsurl

Im developing a customized app that will be used by a couple of people with their own domains. I'm trying to check that if a domain has `SSL certificate`, proceed to HTTPS if not switch to HTTP. I'm trying to change this at `HTTPRequest` method but I get a lot of problems. Can somebody help me to make the right method to check the availability of `HTTPS/HTTP` on Swift?

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your approach?

Comment: Thing is that I don't know the condition which I have to make to check that because I don't want the process to be interrupted and then make the call again. @EridB

Comment: Well should you be checking for the URL scheme first before processing to the HTTPRequest?

Comment: @XhulioHasa what do you exactly mean with the availability of Http/Https?

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details.  How do you know what domain you need to connect to?  How do you intend to check if a domain has an SSL certificate?  Try an SSL connection?  To what port?

Comment: I would advise against doing this. Firstly there are a bunch of security reasons why this shouldn't be done, but secondly you won't be able to release the app to the App store after January 1st 2017 if the app doesn't use HTTPS connections: https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/14/apple-will-require-https-connections-for-ios-apps-by-the-end-of-2016/